# Error in update. I did not find the error. Why is max(C) not found?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

*(Translated from Portuguese with Google Translate)*

I created a table and made an update that should update column B equally to the percentage that C represents in relation to the maximum value of column C.

```
create table z(
a serial primary key ,
b numeric(7,2),
c numeric(7,2)
);

insert into z values(default, 0,20);
insert into z values(default, 0,10);
insert into z values(default, 0,40);
insert into z values(default, 0,80);
```

But it shows an error while executing.

```
update z set b = c / max(c) * 100;
```

> aggregate functions are not allowed in UPDATE

The expected result is:

```
a   b      c
1   25     20
2   12.5   10
3   50     40
4   100    80
```

Comment: Why do you want to store this value? It might change later requiring an update to all rows.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a select within your update:

```
update z 
set b = c / (SELECT max(c) FROM z) * 100;
```

Check it at *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=44df24c263d1cb238b0698dd8f826a64)*

`max(c)` without more context is not part of the SQL standard. However, you can always use a `SELECT` returning a single row with a single column (of the appropriate type) where a value is expected.

That's what you'll get:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    z;

  a |      b |     c
 -: | -----: | ----:
  1 |  25.00 | 20.00
  2 |  12.50 | 10.00
  3 |  50.00 | 40.00
  4 | 100.00 | 80.00
```

And this works not only in PostgreSQL. [See SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=086fe75fc85620305b3e18801e3e45bd), or [MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1d7a489f5471b8dd3384fc49b1a8d46d), or [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=81753f34de05e935a4f9df8387c7dda6), or [SQLite](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=ccc5e1fcc54f1b40da463489fcb25960), or [DB2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=af982434b6355566bdf33cdbd5160658)

Comment: The real question is why store this derived value.